# JPA Hibernate Cannot add or update a child row

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm want to update data in the table with using JPArepository "save" like add function. add it's work but update it not the same.

**Error**

```
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`timesheetdb`.`app`, CONSTRAINT `app_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`batch_id`) REFERENCES `batch` (`batch_id`))
```

This is my code

**App.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "app")
public class App {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="app_id" , nullable = true)
private int app_id;

@Column(name="app_no")
private String app_no; 

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY ,cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE} )
@JoinColumn(name="batch_id" , referencedColumnName = "batch_id",insertable=false, updatable=false)
private Batch batch = new Batch() ;


//get and set
```

**Batch.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "batch")
public class Batch {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="batch_id" , unique = true, nullable = false ,insertable= false , updatable = false) 
private int batch_id;


@Column(name="batch_name")
private String batch_name;

//get and set
```

**log hibernate**

```
Hibernate: insert into batch (batch_name, batch_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into app (app_id,app_no, batch_id) values (?, ?,?)
```

The Problem

1.Why the log is not update ?

2.Sometime i test for see the error i saw new constraint like FKsbmff76rtfh40rncf2110t4pf instead app_id constraint ?

3.The problems it's because I'm wrong with Mapping Many to One ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of,

```
cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE}
```

Try using,

```
cascade = CascadeType.ALL
```

You can refer link https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/ for better understanding.

Also remove new Batch() from the below line

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY ,cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE} )
@JoinColumn(name="batch_id" , referencedColumnName = "batch_id",insertable=false, updatable=false)
private Batch batch = new Batch() ;
```

Comment: Hey Pooja, It would be great if you would explain your answer with description for better understanding.